# How are components referenced to each other in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

```
class TabPane {  
  constructor(
    tabContainer:TabContainer,
    element:HTMLElement
  ) { ... }
  ...
}

class TabContainer {  
  constructor(tabs:Query<TabPane>) { ... }
  ...
}
```

I dont understand the (tabs:Query) part.

1. where does tabs: come from?
2. what about the Query ?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Query-var.html

Answer (score 1):

**Components are reference by importing them and using them as a normal HTML tag on your parent component**, Checkout the following example.

my-app component is referencing the HeroDetailComponent on by importing it via an import command and using it directly.

The two important lines are

the import

```
import {HeroDetailComponent} from './hero-detail.component';
```

the usage of the component by directly adding the tag to the component template

```
<my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
```

---

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Hero} from './hero';
import {HeroDetailComponent} from './hero-detail.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>My Heroes</h2>
    <ul class="heroes">
      <li *ngFor="#hero of heroes"
        [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
        (click)="onSelect(hero)">
        <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
  `,      
  directives: [HeroDetailComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  public title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  public heroes = HEROES;
  public selectedHero: Hero;

  onSelect(hero: Hero) { this.selectedHero = hero; }
}
```

Hero Detail Component looks like this,

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Hero} from './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-hero-detail',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="hero">
      <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
      <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
      <div>
        <label>name: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  inputs: ['hero']
})
export class HeroDetailComponent {
  public hero: Hero;
}
```

[Plunkr Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Angular2 provides dependency injection from constructor. This means that the framework will look for a provider in the current injector for each element defined as constructor parameters.

When you define a parameter of type `TabContainer` in the constructor of `TabPane` which is a sub component of the `TabContainer` one, Angular2 will inject the parent component instance automatically.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tab',
  template: `
    <div>Some tab</div>
  `
})
class TabPane {  
  constructor(tabContainer:TabContainer) {
    (...)
  }
}
```

Angular2 allows also to reference elements in the view of a component. Using the `@Query` decorator, you ask Angular2 for referencing components of a particular kind (`TabPane` in your case) from the component view and even elements. The following shows you how to get the list of all components of type `TabPane` that are used within the `TabContainer` one.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tab-container',
  template: `
    <div>
      <tab></tab>
      <tab></tab>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [Tab]
})
class TabContainer {
  constructor(@Query(TabPane) tabs:QueryList<TabPane>) {
  }
}
```

In this sample the `tabs` property will contain two elements.

Regarding parent / children references, you need to be careful of cyclic dependencies of modules. I mean to make work your sample, you need to have both `TabContainer` and `Tab` components in the same module.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry